# PHP submitting a name in a text box

Tags: php

I have just started learning php. However I am having trouble with the code below. I know it automatically prints out You're not a member... But when I then enter "letmein" it still says I am not a member. Any guidance would be much appreciated

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>A BASIC HTML FORM</title>

    <?PHP

    $username = $_POST['username'];

    if ($username == "letmein") {

    print ("Welcome back, friend!");

    }
    else {

    print ("You're not a member of this site,goodbye");

    }

    ?>


    </head>
    <body>
    <FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST " ACTION = "basicForm.php">


    <INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE ="username" Name="username">
    <INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Login">

    </FORM>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: simple typo in your `FORM` tag partner :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an extra space in the `METHOD ="POST "` of your form.

Change it to `METHOD="POST"`.

Comment: Exactly this. Your form is using the GET method (which is why, when you press the submit button, you'd be able to see the variable in the URL) because you have an extra space so it doesn't recognise the POST call :)